# How can I prove that this equations are linearly dependent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis

Consider a transform $g$ of the form $g(x) = \frac{a+bx}{c+dx}$. Then we must find $a,b,c,d$ satisfying $\begin{align*}
\frac{a + b\frac{1-x}{1+\alpha x}}{c + d\frac{1-x}{1+\alpha x}} + \frac{a + bx}{c + dx} = 1
\end{align*}$($\alpha \gt-1$ is a constant)

Or in other words

$\begin{align*}
\frac{(a+b) + (a\alpha-b)x}{(c+d) + (c\alpha-d)x} = \frac{(c-a) + (d-b)x}{c + dx}
\end{align*}$

which gives us the system of equations

\begin{align*}
a + b &= \lambda(c-a) \\
a\alpha - b &= \lambda(d-b) \\
c+d &= \lambda c \\
c\alpha - d &= \lambda d \\
\end{align*}($\lambda \gt 0$)

We have four equations for five variables ($α$ is assumed to be known).I think one of the four above equation is a combination of three other equation and we have two free variables.But I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: Why do you need $\lambda$? We have $4$ variables $a,b,c,d$, possibly with determinant $ad-bc\neq 0$, so we could apply matrix multiplication and matrix inversion for these [Moebius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_transformation).

Comment: what do you want to do ? find the inverse transformation ? or find if $g(x)$ is inversible ?

Comment: the inverse of transformation......

Comment: and letting $g(x) = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ (the usual notation) you get $g(x) =  \frac{a}{c} + \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{bc-ad}{cx+d} $ that it is clearly inversible iff $ad-bc \ne 0$

Comment: i need the value of variables.......

Comment: Please edit your Post so that it will become clear what you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried here to stick to your method of resolution.

Let us start from the system you have obtained:

$$\tag{1}\begin{cases}
a + b &=& \lambda(c-a) \\
a\alpha - b &=& \lambda(d-b) \\
c+d &=& \lambda c \\
c\alpha - d &=& \lambda d \\
\end{cases}$$

Let us write it in this way:

$$\tag{2}\begin{cases} (1+\lambda) a&+b&- \lambda c&&=0\\
a\alpha &- (1-\lambda)b &&-\lambda d &= 0\\
&&(1-\lambda) c &+ d&=0\\
&&c \alpha&-(1+\lambda)d&=0
\end{cases}$$

It is a homogeneous system ; thus, it always has the null vector $a=b=c=d=0$ as a solution. Of course, this "trivial" solution is not interesting for the issue at hand.

For system (2) to have a non-zero solution, its determinant has to be zero.

This determinant of a block-triangular matrix is easily computed.

Let us equate it to zero:

$$\tag{3}(-1+\lambda^2-\alpha)^2=0$$

as $\alpha > -1$, we can deduce that $\lambda=\pm\sqrt{\alpha+1}$.

Now consider the little system constituted by the 2 last equations of (2) ( or in (1) if you prefer). As its (main) determinant is zero, one of the equations is proportional to the other. Consider thus that the 4th equation can be cancelled. And the third equation gives

$$\tag{4}d=(\lambda-1)c=\pm\sqrt{\alpha+1}$$

The same line of reasoning can be taken for the system constituted by the first two equations in (2), written under the form:

$$\tag{5}\begin{cases} (1+\lambda) a+b=\lambda c\\
a\alpha - (1-\lambda)b =\lambda d
\end{cases}$$

allowing to suppress for example the 2nd equation under the condition that these equations are proportional, i.e.,

$$\frac{\lambda+1}{\alpha}=\frac{1}{\lambda-1}=\frac{\lambda c}{\lambda d}$$

But this is true because of (3) for the first equality and (4) for the second.

Thus, in fact, we are allowed to drop the second and the fourth equality in system (1).

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious what you are trying to do. But there is what you need to check :

Let $G(x) = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ (the usual notation)

- you get $G(x) =  \frac{a}{c} + \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{bc-ad}{cx+d} $ that is clearly inversible iff $ad-bc \ne 0$.
- write that $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}e & f \\ g & h \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}ae+bg & af+bh \\ ce+dg & cf+dh \end{pmatrix}$
  and letting $H(x) = \frac{ex+f}{gx+h}$ you get $$G(H(x)) = \frac{a\frac{ex+f}{gx+h}+b}{c\frac{ex+f}{gx+h}+d} = \frac{a(ex+f)+b(gx+h)}{c(ex+f)+d(gx+h)} = \frac{(ae+bg)x+(af+bh)}{(ce+dg)x+(cf+dh) }$$
  thus, we didn't lie to  you, the composition Möbius transformation really are compatible with the multiplication of $2 \times 2$ matrices.
- hence the inverse transformation is given by $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{pmatrix}$$
  leading to $H^{-1}(x) = \frac{dx-b}{-cx+a}$ since the Möbius transformation stay the same after a multiplication of all the coefficients by a constant.